# How to check if Menu Item has children in Joomla 2.5 with PHP

Tags: php, joomla

I need to check if the active menu has children in Joomla 2.5

EDIT: I had some thinking error: I don't want to check if the active menu has children, i need to determine if the *submenu is displayed*. The Idea of counting children won't work, because if a child item is active it might have no children, but still the submenu is displayed.

I tried something like this:

```
       if ($this->countModules('submenu')) $showSubmenu= true;
       else $showSubmenu = false;`
```

but this won't work, since the module is active on all pages, even if it's empty.

Is there an elegant way to obtain a boolean if there's a submenu or not?

Answer (score 0):

Havent used in 2.5, but earlier versions have "countMenuChildren".  From [Joomla1.6 Docs](http://docs.joomla.org/JDocumentHTML/1.6) there is a starting point to see what it might be called or implemented in J2.5.

Comment: Sorry, it seems I had a thinking error. What I need to determine is whether the submenu is displayed or not.

Comment: Try this then: $ParentitemID = JSite::getMenu()->getActive()->tree[0];